# How to compare two string arrays in Java by passing them as an argument to a method

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to pass two String arrays as an argument to a method in Java and then compare them to check if they are partially equal.

But I am getting compile time error.

```
CE:  error: ';' expected
   String check(String s1[],String s2[]){
}
```

Comment: according to what you've shown that is because the compiler expects you to return a string value, you haven't returned anything yet hence the compiler error. However, if it's about semicolon then the error doesn't belong within the code you've shown.

Comment: What is the method suppose to return?How to define partially equal array?

Comment: You've got to return a value from a non-void method. Specifically, you've got to return a `String` from this method.

Comment: If returning a string doesn't help, I would take a hard look at whatever is *before* this and make sure it is correct.

Comment: I believe you will get more help if you put a bit more of your code. It is inconclusive to look only to the part you paste here.

Comment: please include the code that you're trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
It seams a homework question, so i will give you a Hint:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //define your arrays
        String array1[] = {"Hello", "Java"};
        String array2[] = {"Hello", "World"};

        //call your method which make the comparison 
        boolean check = check(array1, array2);
        System.out.println(check ? "Equal" : "Not equal");
    }

    //Your method must return a boolean, true for equal or false
    private static boolean check(String s1[], String s2[]) {
        //make your condition here
        boolean b = //(your action must return a true or false)..
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: haha yes @OusmaneMahyDiaw i just want the OP to make some efforts and you already show him/her the solution :-)-

Comment: Thanks for the Hint :)

Comment: Can we solve the same question using Regular Expression. Just curious to know about different ways to manipulate this.

Comment: regular expression mmm, maybe, but there are a better way you can easily use `return Arrays.equals(s1, s2);`  @AmeyaAndurekar this will return a boolean true or false

Comment: but Arrays.equals will return true if and if only if they are completely equals and not partially .